# How to properly use Enums in typescript switch

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I have this on one file:

```
export module  Utils {
    export enum DataSources {
        SharepointList = "SharepointList",
        JsonData = "JsonData"
    };
}
```

and on another file I have this:

```
import CustomerDAO from "./ICustomerDAO";
import SharepointListDAOFactory from "./SharepointListDAOFactory";
import JsonDAOFactory from "./JsonDAOFactory";
import {Utils} from "./DatasourcesEnum";


export default abstract class DAOFactory{

    public static SHAREPOINTLIST: number = 1;
    public static REMOTEJSON : number = 2;

    public abstract getCustomerDAO(): CustomerDAO;

    public  static getDAOFactory(whichFactory: Utils.DataSources): DAOFactory {   
      switch (whichFactory) {
        case whichFactory.SharepointList: 
            return new SharepointListDAOFactory();
        case whichFactory.JsonData: 
            return new JsonDAOFactory();      
        default  : 
            return null;
      }
    }
}
```

But I get these errors:

```
Property 'SharepointList' does not exist on type 'DataSources'.
```

Comment: which version of tsc you're using?

Comment: I have 2.2.......................

Comment: the feature you attempt to use is available from 2.4 on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the error you're getting means. It seems like you've made a mistake with your enum though. You're using the *assigned* value and not the enum itself in your switch statement.

```
public  static getDAOFactory(whichFactory: Utils.DataSources): DAOFactory {   
   switch (whichFactory) {
     case Utils.DataSources.SharepointList: 
       return new SharepointListDAOFactory();
     case Utils.DataSources.JsonData: 
       return new JsonDAOFactory();      
     default  : 
       return null;
   }
 }
```

The whichFactory identifier will have some value which is reflected in Utils.DataSources, and you'd want to compare the data to the enum itself. The value will not have the other datasources enum contained within itself.